# how to do encryption in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I want to implement enhanced blowfish algorithm(or any other algo) for encryption in cloud computing on salesforce platform . 
For this i want to create a VF page which has algo code written in apex .
through this page i want save the details (say merchandise object in warehouse app) of object in encrypted form on detailed page .

it means i enter plain text on vf page and it shows cipher text on detailed page.

and in return vf page should display this saved data in decrypted form(plain text).
Is this possible in salesforce and if yes, what extra api or plugins I need.

Comment: Not really clear on what you're asking here. Question is very broad and open ended.
What have you tried so far? what hasn't worked? what has? etc

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for but this may be of help :

Try [`System.Crypto`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm) class :